# code to know whether the file has been downloaded or not

Tags: java, php, file, triggers, download

I wanted to know if there is a way to know whether or not a file has been downloaded completely.
i.e., Is it possible to trigger some action(like send a message to server or alert d user etc.) once a file has been downloaded.

Possibly in java, php.

Thank you.

Comment: @rdlowrey I anxiously await your answer below, sir!

Comment: What is your case? do you download a file from a webserver? What type of webserver is this? etc. a little more information please

Answer (score 3):

Despite comments to the contrary, this *is* possible, though it's not for the faint of heart because it requires some knowledge of the HTTP protocol as well as understanding of file streaming.

Assuming PHP ...

1. Run the file download through a PHP script -- i.e. don't have the web server serve the file directly from disk, have a php script return it.
2. Tell the PHP script to `ignore_user_abort()` -- this will allow the php script to continue to run after the user closes the connection
3. Send a `Connection: close` header *AND* a `Content-Length: 1234` header where 1234 is the size of the file being served.
4. Stream the file to the client using `fwrite`, tracking the number of bytes you've output. Once the number of output bytes have reached the filesize, you know you're finished. The client will have closed the connection but your script will continue to run.
5. Do anything you want to notify yourself or a database or a text log file that the download completed successfully.

Be careful, though, because in a web SAPI you can easily run up against the max time limit in PHP.

---

*UPDATE:*

It's worth mentioning that if you do something like this, you should also add a check to `connection_aborted` in your output loop so that you don't continue to stream output if the client aborts the connection before completing the transfer. This should be common sense, but don't say I didn't warn you.

Comment: Wow! This is awesome. I am always glad to be proven wrong on SO because I learn something new and awesome every time! +1!

Comment: @Matt If I had a dollar for every time someone proved me wrong on this site I'd be a rich man :)

Answer (score 0):

Just send files via phpscript..
e.g http://exmaple.com/download.php?filename=some_filename.txt

```
$file=$_GET['filename'];
if (file_exist($file)){
 send_message_to_somebody(); //DO what ever you want here and then

 $mime = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $file);
 header("Content-Type: " . $mime);
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .  basename($file).'"');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 readfile($file);
}
```

Comment: This will not work, because with the above code php will terminate the process as soon as the client closes the connection. There will be no way for the server to know if the file was actually downloaded in full.

Comment: you right, i didnt read carefully - missed that _complete_ download is important

Answer (score 0):

Write info in database, if download is canceled/aborted, column like "is_downloaded" will be 0, instead of 1... poor description, don't have time.

What is important here is **_destruct()**, that is the trigger for download complete.

```
<?php

class Download
{
  protected $file;
  private $session;
  private $_last_insert_id;

  public function __construct($file, $session) 
  {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->session = $session;
  }

  public function send()
  {

        $info = pathinfo($this->file);

        $query = DB::insert('downloads', array('user_id', 'file', 'path', 'start'))
        ->values(array($this->session->get('id'), $info['basename'], $this->file, DB::expr('NOW()')))
        ->execute();

        $this->_last_insert_id = $query[0];

        $this->session->set('downloading', 1);

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$info['basename'].'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($this->file));

        readfile($this->file);
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
    $aborted = connection_aborted();
    $this->session->set('downloading', 0);
    $query = DB::update('downloads')->set(array('stop' => DB::expr('NOW()')))->where('id', '=', $this->_last_insert_id)->execute();
  }

}
```